# Cannot get Action Cable to output to console log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I am simply trying to get rails to output to the console log. Here is what I have so far:

cable.yml

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
  channel_prefix: enhanced_slack_ui_production
```

activity_channel.js

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("ActivityChannel", {
  connected() {
    console.log("testing");
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
  }
});
```

activity_channel.rb

```
class ActivityChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "activity_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

I am on mac and ran brew install redis, added gem "redis" to the gem file under bootsnap.

Ran bundle install and bundle update. restarted both the redis server and rails server many times but when I visit my homepage (its local so can't share it) nothing shows up in the console. No errors just nothing.

The only setting I see in my development.rb file is: config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true

Tried commenting that in and out, makes no difference.

Running rails 6.14

I checked several tutorials and the steps are always the same so I think my code is good but maybe I am missing something. If not how can I troubleshoot this to figure out why its not connection, any config files or settings that might block it or something like that?

I am trying to make my app update when it detects a push event from slack API so went with this approach, will consider alternative suggestions if there is no solution to this method.

**Adding additional info:**

I noticed on other videos when they startup their server there is a GET log releated to action cable and in the network tab they see cable as an entry. I have neither of those. This is all that shows on my logs after restarting the server.

```
[StatsD] EnhancedSlackUi.request_time:43|d|#controller:home,action:index,request_method:GET,request_format:text/html,response_code:200,response_type:2xx,environment:development
[StatsD] EnhancedSlackUi.request_time:3|d|#response_code:200,response_type:2xx,environment:development
```

Then I load the root page and it does show a message about the broadcast message. Nothing about the logging on activity_channel.js though.

```
Started GET "/" for 192.168.64.1 at 2021-07-24 10:03:05 +0100
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to activity_channel: 2021-07-24 10:03:05.458896 +0100
[StatsD] company_metrics.client.redis.query_count:1|c|#namespace:project-name,environment:development
  Rendering home/index.html.erb
  ChannelPost Load (4.2ms)  SELECT `channel_posts`.* FROM `channel_posts` WHERE `channel_posts`.`interaction_closed` = FALSE
  ↳ app/views/home/index.html.erb:254
  ChannelPost Load (3.1ms)  SELECT `channel_posts`.* FROM `channel_posts` WHERE `channel_posts`.`interaction_closed` = TRUE
  ↳ app/views/home/index.html.erb:271
  ThreadMessage Load (3.5ms)  SELECT `thread_messages`.* FROM `thread_messages` WHERE `thread_messages`.`thread_ts` = '1627075058.000200'
  ↳ app/views/home/index.html.erb:318
  Rendered home/index.html.erb (Duration: 126.5ms | Allocations: 2820)
Completed 200 OK in 143ms (Views: 131.4ms | ActiveRecord: 16.1ms | Allocations: 3405)
```

My connection.rb file contents

```
# typed: strict
# frozen_string_literal: true

module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
  end
end
```

My route file is here:

```
# typed: strict
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root "home#index"
  get "home/index"
  post "/events",  to: "slack#events"

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  post "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute"
end
```

And my home controller is here:

```
# typed: true
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "date"

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @open = ChannelPost.where(interaction_closed: 0)
    @closed = ChannelPost.where(interaction_closed: 1)
    @threads = ThreadMessage.where(thread_ts: "1627075058.000200")

    ActionCable.server.broadcast('activity_channel', Time.now)
  end

  def format_date(date)
    @new_date = date.strftime("%I:%M%p")
  end
  helper_method :format_date
end
```

The page I am trying to look for the broadcast message is on root which is home/index

One other thing, I am using a dev environment so instead of localhost I access the pages with a customized url i.e my_project_name.mycompany.com

In my hosts file I have this:

```
192.168.64.243  my_project_name.railgun
192.168.64.243  my_project_name.mycompany.com
```

I also see this in my hosts:

```
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

When I startup my server it shows:

```
Running /Users/mypath/project-name/bin/rails server -b 192.168.64.1 -p 53835 from dev.yml

* Listening on http://192.168.64.1:53835
Use Ctrl-C to stop
[warmup] Ready to accept requests: 0.0.0.0:8081
[asset server] Serving assets from:
    • http://192.168.64.254:53835
```

Then further down:

```
[warmup] Destroyed all connections
[sewing-kit] Your app is accessible at https://project-name.companyname.com (Ctrl-T to open link in browser)
[warmup] Closed listener
[server] Running with latest changes
started react-server on 0.0.0.0:8081
```

Comment: could you show the server logs ? could you also show your `channels/application_cable/connection.rb` ?

Comment: Hi Lam, I added more information as requested, appreciate you taking a look.

Comment: i guess that the log `[ActionCable] Broadcasting to activity_channel ...` appears before the logs `ActivityChannel is transmitting ...` and `ActivityChannel is streaming ...`, right ?

Comment: i think you send broadcast before the connection cable established, you could try send on another thread with delay: `Thread.start do sleep 1 ActionCable.server.broadcast('activity_channel', Time.now) end`

Comment: If I put sleep 10, it appears in the terminal 10 seconds after the page loads but never in the console.log. Why is it appearing in the terminal but not the console? Where is the most likely config error based on that? I do not have an activity controller, I assumed it could broadcast to any controller or does the controller have to match the channel name?

Comment: did you call `console.log` on `received(data)` ?